# Was I sold all male guppies?

Tags: fish, gender-differentiation

I bought 2 male and 5 female guppies. (There was a language barrier, but I ordered mums and dads, so really simple words ^^)

Now, as longer I look at them, I am nearly sure they sold me all males... I was soon at my way home sure, they did not sold me Endler's guppies, to be precise, they sold me one male Endler as one of the females. But I thought "Okay, 3 male + 4 female could work..."

I add some pictures, the red ones all look alike (should be 4 females), the long tailed blue ones should be 2 males and the mixed color one is the male Endler, I assume.

But the red ones have the shape of males. I miss the gravity spot and the anal fin looks more slim than a triangle.

(And a second appologize for the quality of the pictures. Who tried knows, how hard it is to make good pictures...)

[image: Endler]

[image: Two red]

[image: Single red]

[image: Single blue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the anal fin, I can estimate that you are right. Unless you "transgenderize" them, they will not make many babies.

However, some of the pictures are quite blurry, and I cannot see the anal fin properly.

I do not know if (in guppies) male can become females or females -> males (like in the case of other fishes).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not need to breed them. But they follow each other around, stressing themself. It does not look like a happy life for them.

Comment: Maybe they follow each other to kill the boredom :)